# Filter values ​from many2one fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

Please help, I want to filter values ​​from fields that are in many2one.
I have tried various ways, but still have difficulties in understanding.

so this my code;

```
zona_parkir=fields.Char('Zona Parkir', related='location_id.zone_id.name', readonly='True')
location_id=fields.Many2one('parking_location', string='Lokasi', required='True')
 class ParkingLocation(models.Model): #parking_location
    _name='parking_location'
    _rec_name='name'

    name=fields.Char('Lokasi') 
    zone_id=fields.Many2one('parking_zone', string='Zona')

class ParkingZone(models.Model):
    _name='parking_zone' #parking zone
    _rec_name='name'

    name=fields.Char('Zona Parkir')    billing=fields.Float('Tarif')
    information=fields.Text('Keterangan')
 parking_log_ids=fields.One2many('parking_log','parking_log_id',string='Log Parkir')class ParkingLog(models.Model):
    _name='parking_log'
    _rec_name='vehicle_id'

    vehicle_id=fields.Many2one('vehicle',string='Nomor Kendaraan')
    vehicle_type_id=fields.Char(string='Jenis Kendaraan', related='vehicle_id.vehicle_type.name', readonly='True')
    rate_id=fields.Float('Tarif / Jam', related='vehicle_id.vehicle_type.billing')
    user_id=fields.Many2one('res.users',string='Juru Parkir', default=lambda self: self.env.user, readonly='true')
    parking_log_id=fields.Many2one('parking_session', string='Sesi Parkir', readonly='True')

    total_rate=fields.Float(string='Total Biaya Parkir',states={'in' : [('readonly', 'False')], 'paid' : [('readonly', 'False')]}, store='True', readonly='True', compute='action_close', track_visibility='onchange')
    parking_point_id=fields.Many2one('parking_point',string='Titik Parkir')
    parking_location_id=fields.Char('Lokasi Parkir', related='parking_log_id.location_id.name',readonly='True')
    parking_zone_rate_id=fields.Char('Zona Parkir', related='parking_log_id.zona_parkir',readonly='True')
    parking_hours=fields.Float('Lama Parkir', store='True', readonly='True', compute='action_close', track_visibility='onchange')


class Vehicle(models.Model):  
    _name='vehicle'
    _rec_name='vehicle_number'

    vehicle_type=fields.Many2one('vehicle_type',string='Jenis Kendaraan',ondelete='cascade')
    vehicle_number=fields.Char(string='Nomor Kendaraan'
class VehicleType(models.Model):
    _name='vehicle_type'

    name=fields.Char('Jenis Kendaraan')
    billing=fields.Float('Tarif')
```

so the point is,  when I select ('location_id')

suppose I make 3 zones in that field

```
zone X = B = 2 and C = 3 
zone Y = B = 1.5 and C = 2.5 
zone Z = B = 1 and C = 2
```

Then the value, I previously inputted has been recorded in the "billing" field and when I "add item" in the o2m field, the value in it is the filter result from the zone of one of the zones I selected.

What do I think I should do?

maybe there is my code that is not supposed to exist / is not suitable.
also ask for advice.

I will appreciate all forms of answers, thank you very much.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Why are there two fields at the top of your code, don't belonging to a class/Model? Maybe you can describe your Workflow more detailed?

Comment: thanks for response,

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you mean, but as far as I guess, you want to change the domain of an o2m field (I guess parking_log_ids) and also update the value of the billing field. But the problem is that these fields are in another model, and there isn't any relation between these two models in your code. Have you updated code from tht time, can you gives us a heads up with your progress?

Comment: Also, parking_log_ids and parking_log_id are pointing to different co-models, generally it is not a good practice. 
And finally, you don't have to add `_rec_name = 'name'` because its default value is actually 'name'!